# I have deployed my app on railway, and it sends me worker errors about [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT

Tags: flask, deployment, worker, railway

**I am Using Flask for my Web app and it includes machine learning. **
It works 100% in local.
I do not know what seems to be the problem upon deploying it.

**Here are the Deployment logs on my Railway Pro Plan**

[2023-11-11 15:25:32 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0

[2023-11-11 15:25:32 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7822 (1)

[2023-11-11 15:25:32 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync

[2023-11-11 15:25:32 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9

[2023-11-11 15:25:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10

[2023-11-11 15:25:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11

[2023-11-11 15:25:32 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12

[2023-11-11 15:26:02 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9)

[2023-11-11 15:26:02 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10)

[2023-11-11 15:26:02 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11)

[2023-11-11 15:26:02 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:12)

[2023-11-11 15:26:03 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?

[2023-11-11 15:26:03 +0000] [137] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 137

[2023-11-11 15:26:03 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?

[2023-11-11 15:26:03 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:11) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?

[2023-11-11 15:26:03 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:12) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?

I have tried to increase my workers, but it still does not work, I also tried to redeploy it several times.